# Setting datasources with Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am looking for a SIMPLE example for setting a datasource (jdbc) from a configuration server running Spring Cloud. I've read through the Spring.io docs for Spring Cloud and find them VERY confusing.

Does anyone know of a place to find a simple example? I've tried to run the stuff they have on Github, but they don't build.

Comment: Do you have errors that you could share for the samples not building?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Configuring a datasource is the same as in [vanilla spring boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource)
*with the exception* that the configuration will be loaded from a spring-cloud config server.  So instead of putting the properties in `application.properties`, you put it in `<myapplication>.properties`, where `<myapplication>` is the name of your app defined in `spring.application.name`.

So if your app is named `myapplication`, then you put the following in `myappliction.properties` (which is hosted by the config server):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh... I see what you are saying... hmm... that makes MUCH MORE SENSE... and what if I wanted to run the app under a different profile?

Comment: you add `-<profilename>` to the properties file name.  So for the `myprofile` profile the filename would be `myapplication-myprofile.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You Could also put It in application.yml if you have the yaml lib on your classpath

```
spring:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql 
      username: username
      password: password
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```