# Cannot connect to mysql instance after migration from Springboot to Springcloud

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm having some trouble getting my Spring cloud application to connect to a MySQL instance. A minimal version of my code can be found on [my github](https://github.com/CaliCoder9/spring-cloud-mysql)

The app fetches information from a config server, including the location of my DB instance. I followed the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439839/setting-datasources-with-spring-cloud) to set the datasource, but it looks like the app is not making a connection, because the app makes some inserts to the DB at startup that I'm not seeing.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm new to working with the Spring framework.

Edit:
I am now getting the following error

> Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not
>   specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured

It's odd because spring.datasource.url is set in testapp.properties in the config server. I do see the following line in the log

> Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a differ ent
>   definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=false;  primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari;
>   factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; d
>   estroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
>   with [Root bean : class
>   [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=tr ue; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path r esource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]

I am not too familiar with Hikari. Is one of the dependencies I included in my build.gradle overriding the url?

Comment: What is the actual exception you are getting?

Comment: Hello CaliCoder9. Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Comment: The app runs the data.sql script which does some inserts into the DB upon start up. This script does not run after the switch to using the config server, and there's no connection to the DB.